# Assignment of "null" type inferred as "any"

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint, nrwl-nx

I'm seeing a lack of type error reporting with a function parameter:

```
private _toggle(updates: I_Type | null) {
  const should_toggle = this.thing && !updates.foo

  // ...
}
```

`updates` should be either of type `I_Type` or `null`. However, `!updates.foo` does not show type errors when optional chaining is not used. I.e. a type error should only not show if `!updates?.foo` has the `?.` operator.

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, or perhaps my eslint/tslint config is wrong. Shouldn't `!updates.foo` cause a type error?

**Update**

Per VLAZ's comment, the solution is to add `strict` to tsconfig `compilerOptions`.

Comment: Do you have the [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) compiler option or [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) enabled?

Comment: @VLAZ that was it - big thank you. Added `strict: true` to tsconfig compilerOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Per VLAZ's comment in the question, the solution is to add `strict` to tsconfig `compilerOptions`.